# Extending core class in plugin

Tags: customization

Hi I am writing a plugin and would like to extend a class in the wp-includes folder. I mean that literally like

```
class my_class extends wp_includes_class_x{ ... }
```

However when attempting this I get a `class x not found` error but I know the class is being used by Wordpress. So I try an `include_once(path_to_class)` within my plugin file and that gives me a `Cannot redeclare class` error. Should I be calling the `include` on a special action hook?

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks guys

EDIT

My plugin is OO and so I call `$my_plugin = new My_Plugin_Class();` in my plugin file. Inside this main class I try to instantiate an instance of the class that extends the wp_includes class that I don't wish to name so that I can keep my project a surprise

```
$my_plugin = new My_Plugin_Class();

class My_Plugin_Class{

    public function __construct(){
    $wp_include_class_extension = new WP_Class_Extension();
    }

}

class WP_Class_Extension extends Some_Core_Class{
    public function __construct(){
    //blah blah
    }
}
//CAUSES ERROR class Some_Core_Class not found
```

EDIT

Found a solution - see comments below - thanks for the help guys

Comment: Can you provide a more specific example of what you're trying to do? I don't think `wp_includes_class_x` is a valid class...

Comment: Thats just an example fake class - I am extending a real class but I don't want to name it until I have finished the project - it is an open source project but I still wish to retain an element of surprise.

Comment: Quite frankly, that obscurity will probably push people away from your question...I'm certainly not gonna try to writeup an answer with zero knowledge of what's going on. Close Voted.

Comment: Dude can you not understand my situation, I am working on a cool new feature to do with beta files in the Wordpress Core and I want it to be a surprise - so posting my work in raw form would reveal to everyone. Its a great feature that will go open source but I wish to be the first to achieve it - is that so bad?

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys - I found a solution. Turns out core was including the file at certain times only, so instead of declaring it in my plugin file I simply moved the extending class to a separate file and called an include on that file when needed - knowing that the parent class would be included at that time. Thanks for the help and I'll release the code open-source soon.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Widgets API page on the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) has a great snippet for extending a class (in this case the WP_Widget class).  This should be pretty clear overall.  Be sure you're using the standard name of the class and make sure it's an actual class and not just a function.

```
/**
 * Adds Foo_Widget widget.
 */
class Foo_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Register widget with WordPress.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'foo_widget', // Base ID
            'Foo_Widget', // Name
            array( 'description' => __( 'A Foo Widget', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
        );
    }

    /**
     * Front-end display of widget.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::widget()
     *
     * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
     * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );

        echo $before_widget;
        if ( ! empty( $title ) )
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
        ?>Hello, World!<?php
        echo $after_widget;
    }

    /**
     * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::update()
     *
     * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
     * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
     *
     * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
     */
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );

        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * Back-end widget form.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::form()
     *
     * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
     */
    public function form( $instance ) {
        if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
            $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
        }
        else {
            $title = __( 'New title', 'text_domain' );
        }
        ?>
        <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
        </p>
        <?php 
    }

} // class Foo_Widget

// register Foo_Widget widget
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', 'register_widget( "foo_widget" );' ) );
```

Comment: Thanks but my knowledge of extending classes in PHP is fine. Say the class name in the include folder is WP_Foo_Helper then my class would look like `class My_Class extends WP_Foo_Helper{}` because I am assuming the class has been loaded. My problem is that I'm getting no class found errors and then when I include the file containing the class I get a cannot redeclare class error

Comment: Don't take offense, we get all levels here.  How are you adding your action (see the last line of code)?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't offended just trying to highlight the problem.

Comment: Just making sure - but to answer your question there's really no special way to extend classes in WP.  If you were extending the Walker class for a custom nav, you'd use `class Walker_Child_Classes extends Walker_page {  // code }` - same as usual.  Without seeing your code or knowing what class you're extending, it's going be really difficult to get help here.

Comment: Okay thanks I appreciate the help anyway, I may post my code direct if needed